# Select interaction: show highlighted feature above selected feature

Tags: openlayers

so, I am trying to highlight clustered features when selecting them using `ol.interaction.Select`. First I use select interaction to capture the click behaviour on a clustered feature. Then I access the `features` property to get all features from the clustered feature.

In the use case I'm working on, we then show a popup, displaying information on each feature. On hovering in the popup table, each feature should be highlighted (in red dots). This is done by adding it to another layer and deleting it when it's not hovered over anymore. To simulate this, I've made a [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvBexj) where a feature is added and deleted after a timeout.

The result when I click on the clustered feature (the svg icon) is:
[image: How it is shown]
but it should be:
[image: how it should be]

Somehow the selected point, from `ol.interaction.Select` is always shown on top of any other layers. I've tried setting zIndex on layers, but that does not seem to affect anything.

So my question is, is there a way to show the red highlighting dots above the feature created by the select interaction?